# How do I update the Failed Tests and Pass Rate fields for a VSTS Test Run using the REST API?

Tags: rest, azure-devops

The developers at my company are in the process of incorporating VSTS into our testing.  I am developing unit tests for our code, using the VSTS Rest API to post the results of the tests, grouped in test runs.

My problem is that I am unable to update the test run to show the number of failed tests and the correct pass rate.  My demonstration code uses four unit tests, with 3 passing results and 1 failing result.  On the page of test runs, it shows 0 Failed tests and a 0% Pass Rate.

Internet searches haven't yielded any information on how those fields are set or calculated.  I've done some searching in the documentation for the REST API in the hopes that I would just need to set a certain field when calling the endpoints.  Although the Failed Tests and Pass Rate fields are returned as part of the update call, it doesn't seem like you can set those fields directly for a test run.  I haven't found any alternate endpoints that affect those fields.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/runs/update?view=vsts-rest-5.0

So, the question is, in a nutshell: How do I update the Failed Tests and Pass Rate fields for a VSTS Test Run using the REST API?

I am programming in C#, using HttpClients to call the REST API endpoints, and passing the relevant data via JSON.  Everything is created and updated properly in VSTS; it is just these two fields that don't seem to be working.

Comment: What did you put in the request body of your patch call?

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can check the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I am having this issue. I am creating the run, adding test results then closing the test run. On the front end my runs look like this:
[Test run stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOUg0.png)

However all my results show passes within the run like this
[Test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpSa4.png)

Can't understand why this is the case as the graphs on the test runs are correctly picking up the passes and fails.